# STL container requierments

Tags: c++, stl

Does the standard require that `some_container<T>::value_type` be `T`?

I am asking because I am considering different approaches to implementing an STL-compliant 2d dynamic array. One of them is to have `2Darray<T>::value_type` be `2Darray_row<T>` or something like that, where the array would be iterated as a collection of rows (a little simplified. My actual implementation allows iteration in 3 directions)

Comment: In practice, if you want to claim your template "is a container" then it's either because you want to pass it to some generic code that takes a container template as a template template parameter, or it's just a shorthand to abbreviate the definition. In the former case you could look at what the generic code *actually* requires when it names instantiations, and in the latter case you could document your template fully (and in particular make sure that its iterators really are iterators, so they work with standard algorithms) but just not call it a container if you're in doubt :-)

Comment: "to abbreviate the definition" -- I meant abbreviate the documentation, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The container requirements are a bit funky in the sense that they are actually not used by any generic algorithm. In that sense, it doesn't really matter much.

That said, the requirements are on the interface for containers not on how the container is actually instantiated. Even non-template classes can conform to the various requirements and, in fact, do. The requirement is that `value_type` is present; what it is defined to depends entirely on the container implementation.

Comment: Can you please explain your comment about it not being used?

Comment: Not true. 23.2.1 (and Table 96) in C++11 states that if `X` is a container class containing objects of type `T`, `X::value_type` must return `T`.

Comment: They're not used by any algorithm, but I think they may be used by insertion iterators.  (At least, they're the only places I can think of in the standard where a container type instantiates another template.)

Comment: @Angew: All this statements says that `X` is a container whose `value_type` happens to be `T`. There is no requirement that `X` can be spelled as `some_identifier<T>` (for a some identifier `some_identifier`) which is what this question is about. All the statement says is that `X` is the container name whose element types are of type `T` which, clearly, implies that `X::value_type` is `T` (somewhat of a tautology).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, the insertions iterator do use three signatures and a few `typedef`s out of a large number of signatures and `typedef`s.

Comment: @barauch: From a generic programming point of view it doesn't make sense to create abstractions which are not used. One reason why it is a Bad Idea to create such abstractions is that they are likely not to be right. The container requirements are essentially not used. James is right in that a small subset of the container requirements is used by the insert iterators but other than the standard C++ library has no use for them. This is unlike the iterator requirements and the requirements on value types which are heavily used.

Comment: +1, and I'd clarify that there's a distinction to be drawn between what it means for a type to satisfy the container requirements, and what it means for a template to "be a container". We talk about `std::vector` "being a container", but what we actually mean is that `std::vector<T>` satisfies the container requirements for all types `T` that satisfy the requirements for elements of containers (except `bool`).

Comment: @DietmarKühl I must have misinterpreted the question, sorry.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - the container requirements are about documentation; it's far simpler to say "X, Y, and Z satisfy the requirements for a sequence container" than to list what X does and what Y does and what Z does. Think of it as refactoring common code into a function.

Answer (score 2):

Table 96 in §23.2.1 in the standard (c++11) requires a container class `X` containing objects of type `T` to return `T` for `X::value_type`.

So, if your `some_container` stores objects of type `T`, then `value_type` has to be `T`.

Comment: §23.2.4 (7)The associative containers meet all the requirements of Allocator-aware containers (23.2.1), except that for map and multimap, the requirements placed on value_type in Table 96 apply instead to key_type and mapped_type.

Comment: Dietmar Kühl Seems to have a valid point here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342936/stl-container-requierments#comment18208533_13343044

Comment: The quoted statement (23.2.1 paragraph 4) doesn't require anything as it happens! It is a definition of terms. All it states is what the relationship between `X` and `T` is (i.e., that `X::value_type` is `T`). It **does not** state that `some_type<T>::value_type` is `T`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I actually didn't get your point. Looking up the definition of `vector` in the standard, I found the line `typedef T value_type`. So `std::vector<int>::value_type` should be `int`, shoudn't it?

Comment: @MWid: the `T` in that line `typedef T value_type` denotes the first template parameter of `std::vector`. It is not *inherently* the same as the type `T` in the container requirements, which denotes the value type of the container, but that line `typedef T value_type` tells you that *for vector*, they are the same. So yes, `std::vector<int>::value_type` is `int`. Doesn't mean they have to be the same for the questioner's `2Darray`.

Comment: @MWid: The original question is asking if the a user-defined templates `UD<T>` is required to use `T` for its `UD<T>::value_type` to model the container requirements. Most of the standard containers do so but not all (e.g., `std::map<K, T>` uses `std::pair<K const, T>`) but the container requirements do make make this implication. All what is necessary is that there is *a* definition for `value_type`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks, I got the point. But isn't it required, that `value_type` returns the type of the objects stored in a container? So there is actually no choice for `vector`. (The question doesn't say that `T` is the type of the objects stored in `2Darray`, that's my mistake)

Comment: @MWid: Yes, for `std::vector<T>` the `value_type` has to be `T`. In general, you want to have `value_type` be the type of the elements which may be the template argument but it isn't required to be any of the template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Either have a nested container (so `colArray<rowArray<T> >`) or have a single wrapping (`2dArray<T>`), but don't try to mix them. The nested approach allows you to use STL all the way down (`vector<vector<T> >`), but can be confusing and doesn't allow you column iterators etc, which you seem to want.

[This SO answer addresses using ublas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833146/36537), and another suggests using [Boost multi-arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Generally, go for the STL or Boost option if you can. You are unlikely to write something as well by yourself.

Comment: This is more of a practice to learn the in's and out's of STL

Comment: I would still have STL all the way down, since the row_type would have iterators, as well as being able to retrieve column iterators from the `2Darray`. But this is not really the scope of the question, it was just an example of why this might want to be done.